# Does a user coming to my site solely to hit a login button count as a bounce in analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have what seems like a super high bounce rate. I'm trying to understand exactly why.

One thing I've noticed about our traffic is that 60% of it comes from direct traffic. I thought that maybe users were coming to my site `www.mysite.com`and clicking my log in button to take them to `coolprogram.mysite.com`

If a user comes to my site, only to press a single anchor tag which takes them to a subdomain, then does this count as a bounce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are using on your website is basic tracking then yes, this would count as a bounce.

It is possible to set up event tracking on links so that if someone clicks on a high engagement linkthat takes them offsite, then this would trigger an additional hit and therefore they wouldn't count as a bounce. Event tracking can be implemented with the following syntax for Google Universal Analytics

> ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel],
>   [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);

This could be implemented on your site as:

```
> <a href="coolprogram.mysite.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Click',
> 'External Link Click', 'Login coolprogram.mysite.com');">
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Quick question. Would there be any reason to not just put the same exact tracking code on my sub-domain?

Comment: Hi, yes that would work but you would need to consider implementing cross domain tracking and relevant filters to ensure information is processed correctly otherwise data can merge between the two - for instance if you visit the home page on each site, by default the data would count as two homepage views without distinguishing the different websites. This link should help outline implementing cross domain and setting up relevant filters https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en. Customer data can also dilute things like conversion rates if tracked under the same property.

Answer (score 0):

> If a user comes to my site, only to press a single anchor tag which takes them to a subdomain, then does this count as a bounce?

If you (1) track traffic on the login page in question, and (2) do **not** track the subdomain as part of the same site, then yes.

Change either of those things, and you won't see a bounce for that.

To find out if this is the cause of the high bounce rate, I would suggest creating a new web property that is for all of your domain ("mysite.com"). (You may or may not wish to keep this property long-term.) If the bounce rate is high on your current "www.mysite.com" only property but low on the "mysite.com" property, then your theory about your high bounce rate is correct.